# Python beautifulsoup match regex after string

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup and Python to scrape a webpage. I have a BS element,

```
a = soup.find('div', class_='section lot-details')
```

which returns a series of list objects as per below.

```
<li><strong>Location:</strong> WA - 222 Welshpool Road, Welshpool</li>
<li><strong>Deliver to:</strong> Pickup Only WA</li>
```

I want to return the text after each str

```
WA - 222 Welshpool Road, Welshpool
Pickup Only WA
```

How do I get this out of the BS object? I'm unsure of the regex, and also how this interacts with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: How does getting `div` return `li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:</strong>)(.*)(?:</li>)` capture field `\1` `(.*)` would do the work.

Python code sample:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: test = re.compile(r'(?:</strong>)(.*)(?:</li>)')
In [3]: test.findall(input_string)
Out[1]: [' WA - 222 Welshpool Road, Welshpool', ' Pickup Only WA']
```

check it here https://regex101.com/r/fD0fZ9/1

Comment: This works & also gives me a method for other more general cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need regex. If you have your `li` tags in a list:

```
>>> for li in li_elems:
...     print li.find('strong').next_sibling.strip()

WA - 222 Welshpool Road, Welshpool
Pickup Only WA
```

This is assuming that there is only one `strong` element in the `li` and text is afterwards.

Or, alternatively:

```
>>> for li in li_elems:
...     print li.contents[1].strip()

WA - 222 Welshpool Road, Welshpool
Pickup Only WA
```